# Conditional Expectation and Craps Bet

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

I was hoping someone could help be understand a question regarding the conditional expectation of a 'pass' line craps bet and by extension conditional expectation a bit better.

For context,  in a game of Craps there's three possible outcomes when you bet the 'pass' line: $1.$ you win if you roll a sum of $7$ or $11$, $2.$ you lose if you roll a sum of $2,3$ or $12$. $3.$  you roll any other sum, that is $4,5,6,8,9,10$, in which case establishes a 'point-number' that you must roll again before a $7$.

In my question, $i=1,2$ and $N_i$ is the number of trials needed for outcome $i$ to occur and $N := N_1 \wedge N2$. Also in my book the author defined $x \wedge y$ as $min(x,y)$, so $N = min(N_1, N_2)$

$So$, I'm trying to evaluate $E[N_1| N_1 < N_2]$. As far as I understand the theorem that's used for actually evaluating these expectations is $$E[X] = \sum_{i=1}^n E[X|A_i]P(A_i)  $$ where r.v. $Y$ takes outcomes $A_1,..A_n$

So, my main issue comes from actually rewriting $E[N_1| N_1 < N_2]$ and solving for $E[N]$. I tried doing 
$$E[N] = E[N|N_1]P(N1) + E[N|N2]P(N_2)
      \\= 1(p_1) + (1+E[N])(p_2)$$

but solving doesn't give me $E[N]=\frac{1}{p_1+p_2}$ which is what I'm supposed to get.

Anyway, sorry this post is so long-winded, but any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For both of the events $\ \left\{N_1=n \right\}\ $ and $ \left\{N_1<N_2\right\}\ $ to occur, neither outcome $1$ nor outcome $2$ can occur on any of the first $\ n-1\ $ trials, and outcome $1$ must occur on the $\ n^\text{th}\ $. The probability of neither outcome $1$'s nor $2$'s occurring at any trial is $\ 1-p_1-p_2\ $, and the probability of outcome $1$'s  occurring on the $\ n^\text{th}\ $ is $\ p_1\ $.  Since the trials are independent, we have
$$
P\left(\left\{N_1=n\right\} \wedge \left\{N_1< N_2\right\}\right)=(1-p_1-p_2)^{n-1}p_1
$$
and
\begin{align}
P\left( \left\{N_1< N_2\right\}\right)&=\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty P\left(\left\{N_1=n\right\} \wedge \left\{N_1< N_2\right\}\right)\\
&=\frac{p_1}{p_1+p_2}\ .
\end{align}
Therefore
\begin{align}
P\left(\left\{N_1=n\right\} \left| \left\{N_1< N_2\right.\right\}\right)&=\frac{P\left(\left\{N_1=n\right\} \wedge \left\{N_1< N_2\right\}\right)}{P\left( \left\{N_1< N_2\right\}\right)}\\
&=(1-p_1-p_2)^{n-1}(p_1+p_2)
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
E\left(N_1 |N_1<N_2\right)&=\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty n P\left(\left\{N_1=n\right\} \left| \left\{N_1< N_2\right.\right\}\right)\\
&=\frac{p_1+p_2}{\left(p_1+p_2\right)^2}\\
&=\frac{1}{p_1+p_2}\ .
\end{align}

Comment: thank you for the help!

Comment: wait sorry do you mind explaining $P({N1=n} \wedge {N1<N2})=(1−p_1−p_2)^{n−1} p_1$

Comment: I've added an explanation before the equation

Comment: ah thank you so much, ok and sorry one more thing I'm not understanding: I see why $P({N_1=n}|{N_1<N_2})$ is $(1-p1-p2)^{n-1} (p1+p2)$ but then how did we get $∑ nP({N1=n}|{N1<N2})$ = $\frac {p1+p2}{(p1+p2)^2}$

Comment: This follows  from a [known identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series)
$$\ \sum_\limits{i=1}^\infty nx^{n-1}=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}\ $$

Comment: thank you you're a Saint!

Answer (score 2):

Well, to start, the expression you need is:

$$\mathsf E(N_1\wedge N_2) =\mathsf E(N_1\mid N_1<N_2)~\mathsf P(N_1< N_2)+\mathsf E(N_2\mid N_1>N_2)~\mathsf P(N_1> N_2)$$

Well, $\mathsf P(N_1<N_2)$ is the probability that the first roll that is not-outcome 3 is outcome 1. So this equals $p_1/(p_1+p_2)$, where $p_k$ is the probability that a given roll is outcome $k$.

Now $\mathsf E(N_1\mid N_1<N_2)~$ is the expected count of rolls until you roll the first outcome 1 *when given* that you roll the first outcome 2 is rolled after that.

Comment: thanks so much!